# Is this operator on $L^2$ compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

> Let $T: L^2([0,1]) \rightarrow L^2([0,1])$ be a linear and bounded
> operator defined as: $$Tu(t) = \log(1+t)u(t)
>  \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space
>  t\in[0,1]$$
>
> Is $T$ compact? **Justify** the answer.

Hi, I'm having ***a lot*** of issues trying to understand if an operator in $L^2$ is compact or not. May u help me by telling me what is the optimal procedure in order to understand if a given operator in $L^2$ is compact? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no "optimal procedure", as there are lots of ways to express an operator.

One common way to tell if an operator is compact, is to show that it is a norm limit of finite-rank operators.

On the opposite direction, the spectrum of a compact operator is always countable.

For a multiplication operator like yours, it is an easy-to-establish fact that the spectrum of an operator of the form $u\longmapsto f\,u$ is the closure of the image of $f$. That means that, over $[0,1]$, whenever your operator is multiplication by a continuous function its spectrum will be uncountable.

Comment: excuse me I have a further question so. If I have understood you are saying that this operator has an uncountable family of eigenvalues. this family would be:
$\lambda = log(1+t)$. Does this means that for any $t \in [0,1]$ we find a different eigenvalue of T?

Comment: Your operator has no eigenvalues at all. But its spectrum is the range of $\log(1+x)$, which is the interval $[0,\log 2]$.

Comment: Thank you martin!

Comment: Glad I could help :)